# Query not picking up correct end date of staff

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have got MS Access query (in SQL view) that is not recognising the last bit -
AND ((dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE) Is Null Or (dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE)>"12/31/2018"));

That column is basically looking at staff who do not have an end date or have a terminated date in the system after 31st Dec 2018, however my query is picking up records with no end date as well as records prior to 31st Dec 2018.

My full query is below (Looking at sick leave off staff over the year), could someone please let me know what is happening?

```
SELECT dbo_EMDET.DET_NUMBER, dbo_EMDET.DET_G1_NAME1, 
dbo_EMDET.DET_SURNAME, 
dbo_EMDET.DET_DATE_JND, dbo_EMPOS.POS_PDT_HRS, dbo_EMPOS.POS_AV_HR_WK, 
dbo_EMPOS.POS_DAYS_WK, [POS_AV_HR_WK]/[POS_DAYS_WK] AS [average hours in 
day], [LVE_HOUR_TKN]/[average hours in day] AS [average day taken], 
dbo_EMLVE.LVE_HOUR_TKN, dbo_EMLVE.LVE_DAY_TAKE, dbo_EMLVE.LVE_START, 
dbo_EMLVE.LVE_END, dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD, dbo_EMPAY.DET_NUMBER, 
dbo_EMPAY.PYD_COMPANY, dbo_EMPOS.POS_START, dbo_EMPOS.POS_END, 
dbo_EMPOS.POS_L0_CD, dbo_EMPOS.POS_L1_CD, dbo_EMPOS.POS_L2_CD, 
dbo_EMPOS.POS_L3_CD, dbo_EMPOS.POS_L4_CD, dbo_EMPOS.POS_L5_CD, 
dbo_EMPOS.POS_L6_CD, dbo_EMPOS.POS_ALT_CD1, dbo_EMPOS.POS_ALT_CD2, 
dbo_EMPOS.POS_STATUS, [Translation Table].[Code Description], 
dbo_EMPOS.POS_PDT_STAT, dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE, 
IIf(Left([POS_L5_CD],1)="G","Core","Other") AS [Staff Grouping]

FROM ((((dbo_EMDET LEFT JOIN dbo_EMLVE ON dbo_EMDET.DET_NUMBER = 
dbo_EMLVE.DET_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN dbo_EMPAY ON dbo_EMDET.DET_NUMBER = 
dbo_EMPAY.DET_NUMBER) INNER JOIN [max position 2] ON dbo_EMDET.DET_NUMBER = 
[max position 2].DET_NUMBER) INNER JOIN (dbo_EMPOS LEFT JOIN [Translation 
Table] ON dbo_EMPOS.POS_STATUS = [Translation Table].Name) ON ([max position 
2].DET_NUMBER = dbo_EMPOS.DET_NUMBER) AND ([max position 2].MaxOfPOS_START = 
dbo_EMPOS.POS_START)) LEFT JOIN dbo_EMTER ON dbo_EMDET.DET_NUMBER = 
dbo_EMTER.DET_NUMBER

WHERE (((dbo_EMLVE.LVE_START)>"01/01/2018" And (dbo_EMLVE.LVE_START) 
<"12/31/2018") AND ((dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="SIC" Or 
(dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="DOM" Or (dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="ACC" Or 
(dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="WCME" Or (dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="WCMN" Or 
(dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="WCM2" Or (dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="WCM" Or 
(dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="SLWP" Or (dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="SPEC" Or 
(dbo_EMLVE.LVE_TYPE_CD)="SWOP") AND ((dbo_EMPAY.PYD_COMPANY)="PS" Or 
(dbo_EMPAY.PYD_COMPANY)="PSC") AND ((dbo_EMPOS.POS_L3_CD)<>"CGS") AND 
((dbo_EMPOS.POS_STATUS)<>"C") AND ((dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE) Is Null Or 
(dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE)>"12/31/2018"));
```

If you need to know any other further please to assist, please let me know.

Thanks team :)

Comment: Please format SQL as code.  Using indentation to make it readable is especially important for such a long statement.

Comment: The problem is your string date literals.  Dates are delimited using the pound sign (i.e. hash tag character) `#` and not string quotes.  Example:  `#12/31/2018#`.

Comment: @CPerkins I have formatted it now, apologies! I initially to add in # instead of ' around the LVE_START and LVE START, however it ended up picking up dates starting before 01 Jan 2018, and starting after 31 Dec 2018. I did it with the TER_DATE as well. So the # doesn't seem to work but the ' does?

Comment: Gustav's answer may also solve your problem, but for future reference, **`#` is definitely the proper date delimiter** for generating an actual literal date value.  If a date string value ever does work, it's only because either 1) it has been converted into a date value by the SQL engine (interpreter) and so the comparison worked anyway, or 2) the query might only seem to work, coincidentally because the particular string values compared okay.  But you should always attempt to remove the ambiguity in the types yourself.

Comment: Thanks @CPerkins and Gustav I just kept the query how it was and used the ' instead of # and removed the ((dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE) Is Null Or 
(dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE)>"12/31/2018")); line and manually filtered via excel. Still stumped as to why that line doesn't perform correctly at times, but that's ok and i'll investigate further when I have some more time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your "dates" are not *date values* but *text*, thus not to be filtered as expected.

This happens if you use *DateTime2* and the old **SQL Server** ODBC driver. So, either use data type *DateTime* or use the **SQL Server Native Client 11.0** or newer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get a chance, but for now I just manually removed the last line of --- ((dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE) Is Null Or 
(dbo_EMTER.TER_DATE)>"12/31/2018"));